# Does Android's CursorAdapter run in a background thread?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Does the CursorAdapter run on a background thread and posts updates via the UI looper thread? If not what is the best pattern to load data asynchronously from a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier way is using the `AsyncTask` class. `CursorAdapter` does not run on a background thread, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

CursorLoader should be used to load data asynchronously from a ContentProvider, where Loaders automatically run on background threads. A guide to them (as well as information about updating from using managed cursors) can be found [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/), and an example of using one [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html).

The loader classes are available in the v4 support library, so you can still use it back to Android 2.2.